# Is the dipping in VCC caused by inrush current of charging 1 uF and 0.1 uF capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, msp430, inrush-current

I'm powering [MSP430FR5994](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr5994.pdf) microcontroller from a power supply using [a 2.2 V regulator](https://www.digikey.fr/product-detail/en/ablic-u-s-a-inc/S-1313D22-N4T1U3/1662-2522-6-ND/7229564). This regulator can source up to 200 mA. When MSP430 turns on, it starts to charge a 1 uF and 0.1 uF by driving two pins high. The 0.1 uF is a bypass capacitor of ADXL362 accelerometer. By monitoring VCC, I noticed that VCC dips multiple times to 1.4 V till eventually stays at 2.2 V. These dips in VCC cause the system to reboot because MSP40 low operating voltage is 1.8 V.

My question is: Does charging the 1 uF and powering ADXL362 cause these dips, due to inrush current? If yes, how do I deal with inrush current?

I'm a computer scientist with a limited background in electronics.

I appreciate any help and explanation to overcome this issue.

Here is my schematic:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Can you post schematics? But anyway, driving that amount of capacitance directly from an IO pin does sound like it ends up in problems. Which exact MSP430 model is that, please add link to datasheet.

Comment: I edited my question to include the schematic and the msp430 model.

Comment: Is this an issue? Your MCU should not start at too low voltage depending on brownout settings. An external power-OK signal perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried making C13 bigger?  I would try at least a 1 uF, since you need to accommodate at least that much inrush.

Comment: Also, is C13 nice and close to the VCC pins on the msp430?

Comment: @evildemonic I'll replace C13 with 1 uF. In the board layout C13 is not close to MSP430 VCC pins. I'll consider putting it very close in the future PCB rev.

Comment: @winny yes it is an issue for my application. my system is rebooting multiple times before finally stays on.  with each reboot there is high current draw for the peripherals's initializations.

Comment: @evildemonic Thanks. Replacing C13 by 1uF solved this VCC dipping issue. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I still say you are solving the wrong problem. Your MCU should have its UVLO or brownout setting so that reboot at startup won’t happen.

Comment: Yes there are other problems in the description of this query, But we will never know. I thought he already had a 1uF cap, but why pulse and decay it in an uregulated way?  Was it an ESR issue? what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the 1uF is unclear as a "time keeper".  (pump and decay?)

The 25 ohm MSP internal driver will see the low ESR of the cap when  discharged the current surge is limited by the lack of a series R.  Adding one will limit this charge surge  Is = 2.2V/ (25+R).

Whenever the supply sags that is because a load impedance is near as low as the source.

So one lowers the source impedance with more current limit or raises the impedance of the switched load

> Question was: Does charging the 1 uF and powering ADXL362 cause these dips, due to inrush current? If yes, how do I deal with inrush current?

Answer:  Inrush is a tradeoff during charge for ripple or sag during discharge but without a detailed schematic as built, this description can describe many different design problems like a weak battery.

Comment: the purpose of the 1uF is pump and decay.